# What kind of traffic is going to ec2-54-83-181-212.compute?

Tags: unity, networking, amazon-ec2

I'm toying with some tools to monitor the network traffic going to and from my laptop.
Specifically, I'm using `iftop` and `nethogs`.

I am constantly seing traffic with a site reported as `ec2-54-83-181-212.compute` by `iftop`, even when no specific application is running, and I'm wondering what this is.

I suspect it could be a cloud instance of some sort, maybe even a Ubuntu server (for Unity lenses maybe), but I'm not sure how to check this.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you using `seafile` as well? Loading that IP in a browser shows a log-in for Seafile.

Comment: Thanks @dobey, that's it! I effectively have a seafile client running (no more U1 :-( ) and I had a test account on seacloud.cc set up and still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pointed out by dobey](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481805/what-kind-of-traffic-is-going-to-ec2-54-83-181-212-compute/481814#comment641110_481805), running a http browser on the ip shows a Seafile login page.

Indeed, I have a seafile client running, and had a test account set up on seacloud.cc and still running (although my main account is now a self hosted server).

So that's my answer.